# CSS artifacts showing only on Firefox within a flex box

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

i am having an issue with firefox on some computers showing extra artifacts at the end of a flex box. this artifact is not selectable in teh dev tools and doesn't have any dom element attached to it and it surely doesn't look like a css glitch at all.

here is a screenshot :

[image]

the flex box in quesiton is a simple line fo key value with the value being pushed to the right and the key to the left :

```css
.itempage-page-wrapper .section .item[data-v-214933a8] {
  padding: 12px 0;
  display: flex;
}

.itempage-page-wrapper .section .item[data-v-214933a8]:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
}

.itempage-page-wrapper .section .item .label[data-v-214933a8] {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #777778;
  min-width: 128px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.itempage-page-wrapper .section .item .value[data-v-214933a8] {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #0C0C0C;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
  <div class="itempage-page-wrapper">
<div class="section">
  <div data-v-214933a8="" class="item">
    <div data-v-214933a8="" class="label">collection</div>
    <div data-v-214933a8="" class="value">sqdfqsdf</div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

the problem here is that it doesn't show up on the computers I have but does on multiple other computers.

Comment: you did not post the css, only the SCSS. please provide us with the compiled CSS so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: And what does DevTools say about some max/width/flex-basis? It seems to be a gap created by some element width constraint required by the `ellipsis` (...) we can see.

Comment: @cloned i updated the CSS with the compiled version

Comment: @RenevanderLende but it is also present in case we are not supposed to have the (...).

Comment: I created a snippet from the code you posted but I can't see your issue there. Can you add more code so we see and reproduce it?

Comment: @cloned I updated the snippet to work correctly, but for the code, there is nothing else there, it's just that, the entire item list is a duplicate of the code already in the snippet. Also it doesn't happen in chrome or on firefox on my machine, only on some machines, that i don't own.